# javascript variable

Tags: javascript

do we have to declare js variable like this:

```
var x=5;
```

or just simple like this

```
x=5;
```

what is the differences?... will it effect the functionality of the variable?...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`variable_name = 5` would always put the `variable_name` into the **global object** (which is `window` in a browser)

If you are in the `global context` (= not a function context) the two statements are basically the same. But if you are in a function context, `var` makes sure that this variable is only declared within the current context.

So for instance:

```
function foobar() {
    bar = 55;
}

foobar();

window.bar === 55 // true
```

Better:

```
function foobar() {
    var bar = 55;
}

window.bar === 55 // false
```

Conclusion: **always** use `var` within the context of a function. This avoids clobbering / overriding the global object with variables.

Comment: +1 for mention of `window` as global object in a browser environment.

Comment: if the function has declare the variable like this, function(typ){var typ;} do we have to do this? to avoid overriding the global object...

Comment: @Afrig: no. The suched called `Activation object` does take care of all your passed in arguments. It's still only available in the context of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The [`var` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) limits the scope of the variable to the current function. Leaving it off makes a global. [Globals are bad](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/06/01/global-domination/) and [should be avoided](http://javascript.crockford.com/style2.html) as they are a key source of race conditions and scripts interfering with each other.

Answer (score 0):

`x=5` means this variable (after execution) will become global and can be accessed by all other parts in your code(and also by other javascripts).

while `var x=5` will be familiar only to the block which it was declared on, (and it's descendants)

Note that although `x=5` will be global, it will become global only when this line is execute!
So if you place this inside a function, it will become global only after that function is called (for the first time).

Answer (score -8):

It makes no difference - with the second one (x=5;) the variable is automatically declared if it does not yet exist.

I always use the first option however.

Comment: It most certainly *does* make a difference. `function a() { var x=1; }  x=0; a(); alert(x.toString());`.  Get rid of the `var` and see if your results don't change.